# In java, will the program "remember" the result if you call the same function for the second time?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, memoization

This question came up when I was thinking about the algorithm to fast compute the power of a number, say compute `x^n`.

In Java, the recursive part is something like:

```
return power(x,n/2) * power(x,n/2);
```

So after the program has returned the value of `power(x,n/2)`, will it go through the whole recursive process again to compute the value for the second `power(x,n/2)`?

If so, should we store the value in some variable first, then return the square of that value?

Comment: Dependent on the compiler, not the JVM itself, but I believe you are correct that it is not specified.

Comment: What would happen if `power` was nondeterministic?

Comment: @Jeffrey - then memoization would be an invalid optimization.

Comment: @Kevin: since the JVM is a just-in-time compiler of byte code, it could be done in the JVM, too.

Comment: Instead of trying to optimise an inefficient algorithm, I suggest you use just `Math.pow(x, n)` Using this and similar its faster to calculate the result than maintain a cache of results. (And much simpler)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have in mind is called **memoization**: A pure function (i.e. a function whose return value depends only on the argument values) can remember the result for arguments that it has previously encountered.

Memoization is performed by some high-level special-purpose languages like Maple. However, general-purpose languages don't have this (rather complex) behaviour by default.

However, in your case this isn't necessary. Rather than using recursion, your algorithm is better implemented as *iteration*. [Binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) by repeated squaring is the standard algorithm.

Here's some C-like pseudo-code (my Java isn't 100%):

```
// compute pow(base, exponent)

int result = 1;
int term = base;

while (exponent != 0)
{
  if (exponent % 2 != 0) { result *= term; }
  term = term * term;
  exponent /= 2;
}

return result;
```

For some examples, 7 is 111 in binary, so *b*<sup>7</sup> = *b*<sup>1</sup> × *b*<sup>2</sup> × *b*<sup>4</sup>, and we only need to keep track of *one* copy of the running term. Another one: 5 = 101b, so *b*<sup>5</sup> = *b*<sup>1</sup> × 1 × *b*<sup>4</sup>.

<sub>In C++ it's quite easy to build a generic memoizing wrapper for any function `R f(T1, T2, ..., TN)` that stores the memory in a hash map `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<T1, ..., TN>, R>`; upon invocation the wrapper checks if the argument-tuple already exists, and if yes, it returns the value from the map, and if no it performs the computation and inserts the result into the map. I'm sure something similar can be rigged up in Java.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kerrek! In Java you can use a HashMap as well.

Comment: Here's an [example of a generic memoizer for C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729954/596781).

Answer (score 3):

In non-functional languages (where functions can (and often do) have side effects) the compiler can't know (or at least has a very hard time of knowing) whether the function will produce the same value every time.

So, the particular implementation of *power* might know enough to cache the value of a particular power function.  (I suspect that is unlikely.)  OR, a java implementation may "just know" that *power* works that way, and do special shortcuts with that knowledge.

Otherwise, the answer is basically "No".

Comment: I deleted my comment in lieu of better answers here including yours and @Kerrek's.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem with a lot of recursive solutions. (for the fibonacci series, as well).

Typically you would use something called "Dynamic Programming" where you recurse, but check whether the value was computed before ("memoization"). It's extremely doubtful the compiler will optimize this away for you.

I disagree with goto10, because you're doubly calling yourself, the computation time will grow exponentially, so if you really must use code like this, it's far from a premature optimization.

Comment: In this case the running time is O(lgn) instead of exponential :)

Comment: Ah! Sadly no. If it only recursed once, yes. The problem is it recurses **twice**. And each recursion also recurses twice. So if you consider the depth of the stack as `t`, it will do `2^t` computations. Now, combined with the halving, which, as you say, is `lg(n)` this is actually linear on the `n` parameter of his function. I should have been more specific. :)

Comment: Yes you are right it is linear if we do what I wrote in my question. What I really meant was if we cache the result from first recursion somehow.

Answer (score 1):

is this a homework question?

Java, like most programming languages, does not memoize results of method calls by default, as the method call may have other side effects.  In other words, the JVM cannot assume that these two statements are equivalent:

```
 return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)
```

and

```
 int sqrtPower = power(x, n/2);
 return sqrtPower * sqrtPower;
```

The JVM cannot make this optimization - you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: No it's not a hw question. I am preparing for interviews. So your second block of code is what I should do instead? Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Java does not cache the value of method calls. The JIT compiler might optimize some expressions if the code is simple enough to reason over, but this cannot be done in the general case, since there may be side effects (As an aside, some functional languages like Haskell that don't allow side-effects can avoid this problem).

However, if you have an algorithm that is doing these kinds of calculations a lot, you may want to look into memoization to cache the results of previous computations. Dynamic programming uses this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of an arithmetic expression such as that one, is stored in a stack. There is a stack for the different recursive calls and then for each call there is a stack used to evaluate the expression inside the function. That is the mechanism to "remember" partial results at every point of the evaluation.

Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this generically using AOP.Here it goes,

- Intercept call to a method
- Return result if it can be found based on class, method and argument values in cache.
- If not, proceed with call and place the return value in cache.
- Return the result.