# Memoizing a function with two inputs in C++

Tags: c++

I have a function, `f(a,b)`, that accepts two inputs. I do not know ahead of time which values of `a` and `b` will be used. I'm okay with being a little wasteful on memory (I care about speed). I want to be able to check if the output of `f(a,b)` has already been delivered, and if so, deliver that output again without re-running through the `f(a,b)` process.

Trivially easy to do in Python with decorators, but C++ is way over my head here.

Comment: What would be the data type of the input?

Comment: unsigned 64-bit integers

Comment: Here's a [generic memoizer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729954/596781) I wrote.

Comment: These answers so far seem fairly complex... is there a way I can just declare a two-dimensional vector and just retrieve/set that way?

Comment: @JohnSmith: You can't create a vector indexed by a single 64-bit integer, never mind two.  You'd need `2**128` elements!  Just preinitializing it would be very very slow.

Comment: @JohnSmith: you can always hide the complexity behind a simpler interface, but the actual mechanism requires some ground work.

Comment: Well the inputs a and b could be ints, it's just the output that's int 64. Is this OK? (apologies to @EugenRieck for misunderstanding his earlier question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) (or maybe an `std::unordered_map`) whose key is a [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/), or perhaps use a map of maps.

C++11 improvements are probably helpful in that case. Or maybe some Boost thing.

Answer (score 3):

The poster asks:

> I want to be able to check if the output of f(a,b) has already been delivered, and if so, deliver that output again without re-running through the f(a,b) process.

It's pretty easy in C++ using a `std::map`. The fact that the function has exactly two parameters means that we can use `std::pair` to describe them.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

uint64_t real_f(int a, int b) {
  std::cout << "*";
  // Do something tough:
  return (uint64_t)a*b;
}

uint64_t memo_f(int a, int b) {
  typedef std::pair<int, int> key;
  typedef std::map<key, uint64_t> map;
  static map m;
  key k(a,b);
  map::iterator it = m.find(k);
  if(it == m.end()) {
    return m[k] = real_f(a, b);
  }
  return it->second;
}

int main () {
  std::cout << memo_f(1, 2) << "\n";
  std::cout << memo_f(3, 4) << "\n";
  std::cout << memo_f(1, 2) << "\n";
  std::cout << memo_f(3, 4) << "\n";
  std::cout << memo_f(5, 6) << "\n";
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
*2
*12
2
12
*30
```

The lines without asterisks represent cached results.

Comment: Small nitpick, `m[k]` will do another search, which `m.find(k)` already performed. To avoid that, consider using `m.insert()` or `m.emplace()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, you could use tasks and futures. Let `f` be your function:

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    // Do hard work.
}
```

Then you would schedule the function execution, which returns you a handle to the return value. This handle is called a *future*:

```
template <typename F>
std::future<typename std::result_of<F()>::type>
schedule(F f)
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<F()>::type result_type;
    std::packaged_task<result_type> task(f);
    auto future = task.get_future();

    tasks_.push_back(std::move(task)); // Queue the task, execute later.
    return std::move(future);
}
```

Then, you could use this mechanism as follows:

```
auto future = schedule(std::bind(&f, 42, 43)); // Via std::bind.
auto future = schedule([&] { f(42, 43); });    // Lambda alternative.

if (future.has_value())
{
    auto x = future.get();  // Blocks if the result of f(a,b) is not yet availble.
    g(x);
}
```

Disclaimer: my compiler does not support tasks/futures, so the code may have some rough edges.

Comment: I don't think this helps.  You still need a way to look up the `future` object corresponding to a particular `(a, b)` tuple, and if you do that, you could just look up the result instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If `f` is inexpensive, I agree. But as far as I understand, the actual computation of `f` may be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The main point about this question are the relative expenses in CPU and RAM between calculating f(a,b) and keeping some sort of lookup table to cache results.

Since an exhaustive table of 128 bits index length is not (yet) feasable, we need to reduce the lookup space into a manageable size - this can't be done without some considerations inside your app:

- How big is the **really used** space of function inputs? Is there a pattern in it?
- What about the temporal component? Do you expect repeated calculations to be close to one another or ditributed along the timeline?
- What about the distribution? Do you assume a tiny part of the index space to consume the majority of function calls?

I would simply start with a fixed-size array of `(a,b, f(a,b))` tuples and a linear search. Depending on your pattern as asked above, you might want to

- window-slide it (drop oldest on a cache miss): This is good for localized reocurrences
- have `(a,b,f(a,b),count)` tuples with the tuple with the smallest count being expelled - this is good for non-localized occurrences
- have some key-function determine a position in the cache (this is good for tiny index space usage)
- whatever else Knuth or Google might have thought of

You might also want to benchmark repeated calculation against the lookup mechanism, if the latter becomes more and more complex: `std::map` and freinds don't come for free, even if they are high-quality implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way is to use `std::map`. `std::unordered_map` does not work. We cannot use `std::pair` as the key in unordered map. You can do the following,

```
std::map<pair<int, int>, int> mp; 

int func(int a, int b)
{
  if (mp.find({a, b}) != mp.end()) return mp[{a, b}];
  // compute f(a, b)...
  mp[{a, b}] = // computed value;
  return mp[{a, b}];
}
```

Comment: Why do you think we cannot use `std::unordered_map`?  Perhaps one should provide a hash function (I haven't checked it) and that's it.

Comment: Yes, we cannot use unordered_map unless you provide a hash function for it.