# Recursive lambda callbacks without Y Combinator

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, lambda, closures

I wish to create a callback that recursively returns itself as a callback.

The suggested method to recurse is for the function to have a reference to itself:

```
std::function<void (int)> recursive_function = [&] (int recurse) {
    std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

    if (recurse > 0) {
        recursive_function(recurse - 1);
    }
};
```

This fails as soon as you return it from a function:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

volatile bool no_optimize = true;

std::function<void (int)> get_recursive_function() {
    std::function<void (int)> recursive_function = [&] (int recurse) {
        std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

        if (recurse > 0) {
            recursive_function(recurse - 1);
        }
    };

    if (no_optimize) {
        return recursive_function;
    }

    return [] (int) {};
}

int main(int, char **) {
    get_recursive_function()(10);
}
```

which gives a *segmentation fault* after outputting `10` because the reference becomes invalid.

How do I do this? I have successfully used what I think is a *[Y Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator)* (which I'll post as an answer), but it is hugely confusing. Is there a better way?

---

#### Other attempts

I have tried the boring approach of wrapping it in another layer of callbacks:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

volatile bool no_optimize = true;

std::function<void (int)> get_recursive_function() {
    // Closure to allow self-reference
    auto recursive_function = [] (int recurse) {
        // Actual function that does the work.
        std::function<void (int)> function = [&] (int recurse) {
            std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

            if (recurse > 0) {
                function(recurse - 1);
            }
        };

        function(recurse);
    };

    if (no_optimize) {
        return recursive_function;
    }

    return [] (int) {};
}

int main(int, char **) {
    get_recursive_function()(10);
}
```

but this fails in the actual scenario, where the function is being delayed and called by an outer loop:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

volatile bool no_optimize = true;

std::queue<std::function<void (void)>> callbacks;

std::function<void (int)> get_recursive_function() {
    // Closure to allow self-reference
    auto recursive_function = [] (int recurse) {
        // Actual function that does the work.
        std::function<void (int)> function = [&] (int recurse) {
            std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

            if (recurse > 0) {
                callbacks.push(std::bind(function, recurse - 1));
            }
        };

        function(recurse);
    };

    if (no_optimize) {
        return recursive_function;
    }

    return [] (int) {};
}

int main(int, char **) {
    callbacks.push(std::bind(get_recursive_function(), 10));

    while (!callbacks.empty()) {
        callbacks.front()();
        callbacks.pop();
    }
}
```

which gives `10`, then `9` and then segmentation faults.

Comment: Have you tried to simply make the `recursive_function` variable in the first snippet `static`? That way the object won't be destructed when the factory function returns.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works with VS2013...?

Comment: @Niall Probably because [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) sometimes seems to work. My worry is that the `recursive_function` object will be destructed when the factory function returns, leading to said UB when the lambda tries to use the (now destructed) object.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I figured as much. I think making it a member variable could help here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unfortunately, just making it `static` defeats most of the point of having a lambda, in my case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually, I take that back. I can extract the state from the lambda into an argument that gets passed along, which will remove the need for the lambda itself to be non-static.

Answer (score 4):

As you rightly pointed out, there is an invalid reference from the lambda capture `[&]`.

Your returns are functors of various sorts, so I assume that the exact type of the return is not important, just that it behaves as a function would i.e. be callable.

If the `recursive_function` is wrapped in a `struct` or `class` you can map the call operator to the `recursive_function` member. A problem arises with the capture of the `this` variable. It'll be captured with the `this` on creation, so if the object is copied around a bit, the original `this` may no longer be valid. So an appropriate `this` can be passed in to the function at execution time (this `this` issue may not be a problem, but it depends heavily on when and how you call the function).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

volatile bool no_optimize = true;

struct recursive {
    std::function<void (recursive*, int)> recursive_function = [] (recursive* me, int recurse) {
        std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

        if (recurse > 0) {
            me->recursive_function(me, recurse - 1);
        }
    };

    void operator()(int n)
    {
        if (no_optimize) {
            recursive_function(this, n);
        }
    }
};

recursive get_recursive_function() {
    return recursive();
}

int main(int, char **) {
    get_recursive_function()(10);
}
```

Alternatively, if the `recursive_function` can be `static` then declaring it as such in the original code sample may also do the trick for you.

I wanted to add some generality to the answer above, i.e. make it a template;

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

volatile bool no_optimize = true;

template <typename Signature>
struct recursive;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct recursive<R (Args...)> {
    std::function<R (recursive const&, Args... args)> recursive_function;

    recursive() = default;

    recursive(decltype(recursive_function) const& func) : recursive_function(func)
    {
    }

    template <typename... T>
    R operator()(T&&... args) const
    {
        return recursive_function(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

recursive<void (int)> get_recursive_function()
{
    using result_type = recursive<void (int)>;

    if (!no_optimize) {
        return result_type();
    }

    result_type result ([](result_type const& me, int a) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;

        if (a > 0) {
            me(a - 1);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

int main(int, char **) {
    get_recursive_function()(10);
}
```

How does this work? Basically it moves the recursion from inside the function (i.e. calling itself) to an object (i.e. the function operator on the object itself) to implement the recursion. In the `get_recursive_function` the result type `recursive<void (int)>` is used as the first argument to the recursive function. It is `const&` because I've implemented the `operator()` as `const` in line with most standard algorithms and the default for a lambda function. It does require some "co-operation" from the implementer of the function (i.e. the use of the `me` parameter; itself being `*this`) to get the recursion working, but for that price you get a recursive lambda that is not dependent on a stack reference.

Answer (score 4):

All problems in programming can be solved with another layer of indirection, except too many layers of indirection.

My goal is to create a type `recursive<void(int)>` that lets you easily create a recursive lambda.  To do this, you pass in a lambda with signature `void(recursive<void(int)>, int)` -- the first argument is what you invoke in order to do your recursive call.

I then tie it up in knots and make it a fully recursive function with signature `void(int)`.

Here is my implementation of `recursive<Signature>`:

```
template<class Sig>
struct recursive;
template<class R, class... As>
struct recursive< R(As...) > {
  using base_type = std::function<R(recursive, As...)>;
private:
  std::shared_ptr< base_type > base;
public:

  template<typename...Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&... ts) const
  -> typename std::result_of< base_type( recursive, Ts... ) >::type
  {
    return (*base)(*this, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }

  recursive(recursive const&)=default;
  recursive(recursive&&)=default;
  recursive& operator=(recursive const&)=default;
  recursive& operator=(recursive &&)=default;
  recursive() = default;
  template<typename L, typename=typename std::result_of< L(recursive, As...) >::type>
  explicit recursive( L&& f ):
    base( std::make_shared<base_type>(std::forward<L>(f)))
  {}
  explicit operator bool() const { return base && *base; }
};
```

That is, admittedly, pretty complicated.  I did a bunch of things to make it more efficient, such a perfect forwarding.  It also, unlike `std::function`, double checks that the type of the lambda you pass to it matches the signature it wants.

I believe, but have not confirmed, that I made it friendly to make the lambdas signature `void(auto&&,int)`.  Anyone know of a fully compliant C++1y online compiler?

The above is just boilerplate.  What matters is how it looks at point of use:

```
std::function<void (int)> get_recursive_function() {
  auto f =
    [] (recursive<void(int)> self, int recurse) {
      std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

      if (recurse > 0) {
        self(recurse - 1);
      }
    };
  return recursive< void(int) >( f );
};
```

Here we do the popular `auto f = lambda` syntax.  No need to directly store it in a `std::function`.

Then, we explicitly cast it to a `recursive<void(int)>`, which ties it up in knots and removes the `recursive<void(int)>` argument to `f` from the front, and exposes the signature `void(int)`.

This does require that your lambda take `recursive<void(int)> self` as its first parameter, and do recursion through it, but that doesn't seem to harsh.  If I wrote it **just right** it might work with `auto&& self` as the first parameter, but I am unsure.

`recursive<?>` works for any signature, naturally.

[live example](http://ideone.com/QWFnAA)

And, [with delayed calls in outer loop](http://ideone.com/up98cm) it still works.  Note that I got rid of that global variable (it would work with it as a global variable, it just felt dirty to leave it in).

In C++1y, we can [eliminate the type erasure & `shared_ptr` overhead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9732ef12310c7f6) you see above (with the `recursive` object holding a `shared_ptr<function<?>>`).  You do have to provide the return value, as I cannot get `result_of` to untangle my mess:

```
struct wrap {};

template<class R, class F>
struct recursive {
  using base_type = F;
private:
  F base;
public:

  template<class... Ts>
  R operator()(Ts&&... ts) const
  {
    return (*base)(*this, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }

  recursive(recursive const&)=default;
  recursive(recursive&&)=default;
  recursive& operator=(recursive const&)=default;
  recursive& operator=(recursive &&)=default;
  recursive() = delete;
  template<typename L>
  recursive( wrap, L&& f ):
    base( std::forward<L>(f) )
  {}
};

template<class T>using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;

template<class R, class F>
recursive<R, decay_t<F>> recurse( F&& f ) { return recursive<R, decay_t<F>>(wrap{}, std::forward<F>(f)); }
```

Then a slightly different implementation of `get_recursive_function` (where I added some state for fun):

```
std::function<void (int)> get_recursive_function(int amt) {
  auto f =
    [amt] (auto&& self, int count) {
      std::cout << count << std::endl;

      if (count > 0) {
        self(count - amt);
      }
    };
  return recurse<void>( std::move(f) );
};

int main() {
  auto f = get_recursive_function(2);
  f(10);
}
```

the use of `std::function` in the return value of `get_recursive_function` is optional -- you could use `auto` in C++1y.  There is still some overhead compared to a perfect version (where the lambda could access its own `operator()`), because the `operator()` probably doesn't know that it is being recursively invoked on the same object when it invokes `self`.

It would be tempting to allow `operator()( blah )` within the body of a lambda to allow a recursive invocation of the lambda.  It would probably break very little code.

Comment: Wow, thanks. FWIW, the global variable was just to stop the segmentation fault being optimized out; it's not in the real code.

Comment: Being quite new to C++, I have a question. Why use the `Ts` and `L` templates when you could just do (forgive the formatting): `R operator()(As &&... as) const { return (*base)(*this, std::forward<As>(as)...); }` and `explicit recursive(base_type&& f ): base(std::make_shared<base_type>(std::forward<base_type>(f))) {}`?

Comment: @Veedrac `&&` with a fixed value type is an rvalue reference.  `&&` with a deduced type is a universal reference.  I'm going for perfect forwarding in both cases.  In both of your cases, it would restrict how the function is called.  In the first case, it might require arguments to be `move`d into the recursive `self` call in the lambda.  In the second, worse would happen, as `base_type` is **not** the type of the lambda, but rather a `std::function<blah>`, and `std::function`s are not lambdas.  I want to construct a `std::function` shared ptr containing the lambda.

Comment: @Veedrac oh, and `std::function` is overly greedy in its belief that it can be constructed from things.  My code does at least a cursory check that evaluating its argument with the signature will work.  This helps prevent this constructor from being preferred over the move/copy constructors.  As a final aside, capturing a parameter `my_queue& queue` by reference can be undefined behavior under the current standard -- think about capturing a pointer-to-queue instead of a reference that goes out of scope. (There is a corner case standard clause that makes reference capture of references strange)

Comment: @Veedrac [With C++1y `auto&&` support for `self`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/250f406ac7c62d0a)

Comment: You're seriously helpful here; this discussion spurred on a ton of really useful reading. I've finally pieced together how it all works, and I'm impressed.

Comment: @Veedrac now with a C++1y version that reduces overhead a bunch!  It isn't perfect, but it gets close.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround, which is unfortunately complicated, is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

volatile bool no_optimize = true;

std::queue<std::function<void (void)>> callbacks;
```

(I think this is a [Y Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator), but I am unsure.)

```
std::function<void (int)> y_combinator(
        std::function<void (std::function<void (int)>, int)> almost_recursive_function
) {
    auto bound_almost_recursive_function = [almost_recursive_function] (int input) {
        y_combinator(almost_recursive_function)(input);
    };

    return [almost_recursive_function, bound_almost_recursive_function] (int input) {
        almost_recursive_function(bound_almost_recursive_function, input);
    };
}
```

This is the base function; it does not call itself but an argument it is passed. This argument should be the recursive function itself.

```
std::function<void (std::function<void (int)>, int)> get_almost_recursive_function() {
    auto almost_recursive_function = (
        [] (std::function<void (int)> bound_self, int recurse) {
            std::cout << recurse << std::endl;

            if (recurse > 0) {
                callbacks.push(std::bind(bound_self, recurse - 1));
            }
        }
    );

    if (no_optimize) {
        return almost_recursive_function;
    }

    return [] (std::function<void (int)>, int) {};
}
```

So the wanted function can be made by applying the combinator to the almost-recursive function.

```
std::function<void (int)> get_recursive_function() {
    return y_combinator(get_almost_recursive_function());
}
```

When `main` is run, this outputs `10`, `9`, ..., `0`, as wanted.

```
int main(int, char **) {
    callbacks.push(std::bind(get_recursive_function(), 10));

    while (!callbacks.empty()) {
        callbacks.front()();
        callbacks.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already deal with `std::function` that add a bit of overhead all over the place, you can add memory persistence that will only add an indirection at the calling site with a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::function<void (int)>> CreateRecursiveFunction() {
    auto result = std::make_unique<std::function<void (int)>>();

    auto ptr = result.get();
    *result = [ptr] (int recurse) { // c++1y can also capture a reference to the std::function directly [&func = *result]
        std::cout << recurse << std::endl;
        if (recurse > 0) {
            (*ptr)(recurse - 1); // with c++1y func( recurse - 1 )
        }
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this means I have to accept pointers to functions instead of just functions, so is less ideal for me.