# Static variables and functions that are called once for each choice of arguments

Tags: c++, static-members

Here is a simple C++ question.

**Description of the problem:**
I have a function that takes as input an integer and returns a vector of zeros with length the input. Assume that I call the function many times with the same argument. What I want to avoid is that my function creates the vector of zeroes each time it is called. I want this to happen only the first time the function is called with the given input.

**How I approached it:** This brought to mind static variables. I thought of creating a static vector that holds the required zero vectors of each size, but wasn't able to figure out how to implement this. As an example I want something that "looks" like [ [0], [0,0], ...].

If there is a different way to approach such a problem please feel free to share! Also, my example with vectors is a bit specialised but replies that are more generic (concerning static variables that depend on the argument) would be greatly appreciated.

**Side question:**
To generalise further, is it possible to define a function that is only called **once** for each choice of arguments?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use map<argument, vector> as the static instance.

Comment: A static vector (or better a map) of vectors is the right idea, you just need to initialize it lazily.

Comment: It is not clear what your are after, are the vectors you return `const`? Otherwise you will need to make a copy every time anyways. Unless copying if faster than zero-initialization then it might make sense. And it is impossible to make a function that gets executed once per argument set, but it is possible to make a function that does nothing if it is passed same set of arguments as before. It will execute, but make a check and  immediately return, or provide a cached result, etc.

Comment: This technique is called "memoization". See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805969/writing-universal-memoization-function-in-c11.

Comment: There are three ways of interpreting this question that I can see. 1) You want a  function that returns a `vector` by-value, a copy that you then want to change. 2) You want a function that returns a const reference to a vector of zeros that you don't need to change. 3) You want a function that returns a non-const reference to a vector that is initially full of zeros but can be changed. It would probably help to show your code.

Comment: Thanks Chris Drew for the comment. I am looking for 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, I don't think you will get the benefit you are expecting.

I wrote a quick benchmark to compare the performance of repeatedly creating a vector of zeros. The first benchmark uses the standard vector constructor. The second uses a function that only creates the vector the first time and stores it in a map:

```
const std::vector<int>& zeros(std::size_t size) {
    static std::unordered_map<size_t, std::vector<int>> vectors;
    auto find = vectors.find(size);
    if (find != vectors.end())
        return find->second;
    auto insert = vectors.emplace(size, std::vector<int>(size));
    return insert.first->second;
}

std::chrono::duration<float> benchmarkUsingMap() {
  int sum = 0;
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for (int i = 0; i != 10'000; ++i) {
    auto zeros10k = zeros(10'000);
    zeros10k[5342] = 1;
    sum += zeros10k[5342];    
  }

  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                      
  std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << "\n";
  return end - start;
}

std::chrono::duration<float> benchmarkWithoutUsingMap() {
  int sum = 0;
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for (int i = 0; i != 10'000; ++i) {
    auto zeros10k = std::vector<int>(10'000);
    zeros10k[5342] = 1;
    sum += zeros10k[5342];    
  }

  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                                   
  std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << "\n";
  return end - start;
}                          

int main() {
  std::cout << "Benchmark without map: " << benchmarkWithoutUsingMap().count() << '\n';
  std::cout << "Benchmark using map: " << benchmarkUsingMap().count() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Benchmark without map: 0.0188374
Benchmark using map: 0.134966
```

So, in this case, just creating the vector each time was almost 10x faster. This is assuming you want to create a mutable copy of the vector of zeros.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I was really interested in improving the speed at which performs that's why I wanted to avoid to recreate the zero vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a map of sizes and vectors, one vector for each size:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cstddef>

std::vector<int>& get_vector(std::size_t size)
{
    static std::map<size_t, std::vector<int> >  vectors;
    std::map<size_t, std::vector<int> >::iterator iter = vectors.find(size);
    if (iter == vectors.end())
    {
        iter = vectors.insert(std::make_pair(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0))).first;
    }
    return iter->second;
}
```

Comment: You may reuse `find`/`insert` result to avoid to re find with `operator[]`

Comment: Note that this returns a non-const reference which means the caller can make changes to the vector in the map and subsequent calls will not get a vector of zeros. This may not be what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

If each vector needs to be a separate instance then you will have to have a construction for each instance.  Since you will have to construct each instance you can make a simple `make_int_vector` function like:

```
std::vector<int> make_int_vector(std::size_t size, int fill = 0) 
{ 
    return std::vector(size, fill); 
}
```

The returned vector will either be moved or be elided with [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Comment: Does that make any sense? I mean what is the difference from using `std::vector<int>(size)` in-place?

Comment: That sounds useful, but does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a cache. The hard part is how long an entry should exist in the cache. Your current requirement seems to be an eternal cache, meaning that each entry will persist for ever. For such a simple use case, à static map is enough:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
T cached(T (*funct)(U arg)) {
    static unordered_map<U, T> c;
    if (c.count(arg) == 0) {
        c[arg] = funct(arg);
    }
    return c[arg];
}
```

The above is returning a value,which will require à copy. If you want to avoid the copy, just return a reference, but then, if you change one of the vectors, the next call will return the modified value.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
&T cached(T (*funct)(U arg)) {
    static unordered_map<U, T> c;
    if (c.count(arg) == 0) {
        c[arg] = funct(arg);
    }
    return c[arg];
}
```