# Composable C++ Function Decorators

Tags: c++, c++14, composition, generic-programming, python-decorators

Python has a very useful feature of [function decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), which, moreover, allows composition. For example, if write a function `foo`, then you can state that you would like `foo` to be [memoized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), but also [retried](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying)  more than a single time in case of a cache miss in which `foo` also raises an exception, by:

```
@lru_cache
@retry
def foo(...):
```

Decorator composability allows developing functions like `foo` and individual function decorators independently, and then mixing them as needed. It would be nice if we could do so in C++ as well (to the extent possible).

While there are several questions on StackOverflow regarding function decorators, they all seem to generate non-composable ones, due to rigid assumptions on the signature of the decorated function. E.g., consider the excellent top-voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805969/writing-universal-memoization-function-in-c11). The decoration is of the form

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
std::function<R (Args...)> memo(R (*fn)(Args...)) {
```

Consequently, it [cannot be applied to the result of itself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b984d15f1b99e01d) (admittedly not much of an issue for the specific decorator use of memoization).

How can we write composable function decorators, then?

Comment: The example you give is not very convincing; there's nothing in that implementation that requires it to take a function pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to create *composable function decorators* is by using a set of *mixin* classes.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template<class T>
struct LoggerDecoratorA: public T {
    template<class U>
    LoggerDecoratorA(const U &u): T{u} { }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const ->
        typename std::enable_if<
            not std::is_same<
                typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type,
                void
            >::value,
        typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type>::type
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "> logger A" << endl;
        auto ret = T::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cout << "< logger A" << endl;
        return ret;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const ->
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<
                typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type,
                void
            >::value,
        typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type>::type
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "> logger A" << endl;
        T::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cout << "< logger A" << endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct LoggerDecoratorB: public T {
    template<class U>
    LoggerDecoratorB(const U &u): T{u} { }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const ->
        typename std::enable_if<
            not std::is_same<
                typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type,
                void
            >::value,
        typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type>::type
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "> logger B" << endl;
        auto ret = T::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cout << "< logger B" << endl;
        return ret;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const ->
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<
                typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type,
                void
            >::value,
        typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type>::type
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "> logger B" << endl;
        T::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cout << "< logger B" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::function<int()> fn = [](){
        using namespace std;
        cout << 42 << endl;
        return 42;
    };

    std::function<void()> vFn = [](){
        using namespace std;
        cout << "void" << endl;
    };

    using namespace std;

    decltype(fn) aFn =
        LoggerDecoratorA<decltype(fn)>(fn);
    aFn();

    cout << "---" << endl;

    decltype(vFn) bVFn =
        LoggerDecoratorB<decltype(vFn)>(vFn);
    bVFn();

    cout << "---" << endl;

    decltype(fn) abFn =
        LoggerDecoratorA<LoggerDecoratorB<decltype(fn)>>(fn);
    abFn();

    cout << "---" << endl;

    decltype(fn) baFn =
        LoggerDecoratorB<LoggerDecoratorA<decltype(fn)>>(fn);
    baFn();
}
```

I'm not sure what of the problems you mentioned it actually solves, but feel free to ask for changes and I'll try to update it if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it fits your expectations. It works well with functions only, but it was what you were looking for, wasn't it?

Comment: thanks again - I plan to read this at great length with interest tomorrow.

Comment: @AmyTavory I was thinking about that, I guess you can also easily implement memoization and retry logic by using this approach, at least as long as you correctly combine you parts. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I agree that memoization can be handled this way, but only partially (it's a problem of the language, not your solution). AFAICT, any noninvasive memoization decorator to a recursive function, will not memoize the recursive call. So, e.g., a memoized version of Fibonacci will still be exponential, but at least it will cache the final result.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create composable function decorators, is by relaxing the assumption on the signature taken by the decorator. Say we have

```
template<class Fn>
struct foo_decorator
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    auto operator()(Args &&...args) const ->
        typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type;
};

template<class Fn>
foo_decorator<Fn> make_foo(const Fn &fn) {return foo_decorator<Fn>();}
```

As can be seen, both `make_foo` and `foo_decorator` are parameterized by `class Fn` which can be virtually anything at that point. Hence they can take both a lambda function or a functor, for example. The arguments taken (and the return type) are (compile-time) deferred to the invocation, where the deduced template parameters of a C++ function call will fill in the rest of the details as needed.

Using this, here is a simple logging decorator:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>     

template<class Fn> 
struct logger
{   
    logger(const Fn &fn, const std::string &name) : m_fn(fn), m_name{name}{}

    template<typename ...Args>
    auto operator()(Args &&...args) const ->
        typename std::result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type
    {   
        std::cout << "entering " << m_name << std::endl;
        const auto ret = m_fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        std::cout << "leaving " << m_name << std::endl;
        return ret;
    }

private:
    Fn m_fn;
    std::string m_name;
};  

template<class Fn> 
logger<Fn> make_log(const Fn &fn, const std::string &name)
{   
    return logger<Fn>(fn, name);
}   

int main()
{   
    auto fn = make_log([](double x){return std::sin(x);}, "sin");
    std::cout << fn(4.0) << std::endl;
}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f78c03d84c0278f) is a build of this decorator, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ad072c97d6081d6) is a build of a retrying decorator, and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aebd7b3c02f282ab) is a build of a composition of them.

One drawback of this approach is for cases where the decorator has a state relying on the signature of the function, e.g., the original case of memoization. It's possible to deal with this using type erasure (see a build [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6374858457ff59e)), but this has a number of drawbacks, one of which is that errors which conceptually could have been caught at compile time, are now caught at runtime (when the type erasure detects illegal use).