# Is std::string guaranteed not to give back memory spontaneously?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, heap-memory, stdstring

Is it guaranteed by the standard that `std::string` will not give back allocated memory spontaneously if reassigned from a string of a smaller size?

In other words:

```
std::string str = "Some quite long string, which needs a lot of memory";
str = "";
str = "A new quite long but smaller string"; // Guaranteed to not result in a heap allocation?
```

I ask because i'm depending on this to avoid heap fragmentation.

Comment: if the new string allocation is less than the previous allocation, no allocation occurs. If the new string requires more allocation than the current, a reallocation occurs. Similar to a std::vector.

Comment: Strings reuse their buffers when assigned to shorter strings, so in your program there is only one allocation for the string. Unfortunately I can't find conveniently any citation from the standard on mobile

Comment: Even if a string did "give back memory spontaneously", that is insufficient to avoid heap fragmentation. A string uses an allocator (by default, an object of type `std::allocator<char>`, but that can be changed) to allocate and deallocate memory, and the allocator may use a lower-level mechanism again (e.g. variants of operators `new` and `delete`) to actually allocate and deallocate. If *any* of those steps elect to not release memory to the lower-level layer, there is potential impact on heap fragmentation.

Comment: _I ask because i'm depending on this to avoid heap fragmentation._ This was exactly the reason why I wrote my own memory _controller_ for `std::string`

Comment: If you need to guarantee this behaviour, you can always used your own custom allocator

Comment: @AlBundy: what's a memory controller?

Comment: In my own experience, if I have to utter the phrase "I'm dependent on avoiding heap fragmentation," its a very good time to start considering identifying precise low level requirements, and potentially rolling your own allocation routines.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### No guarantee whatsoever.

[`[string.cons]/36`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.cons-36) defines assigning a `const char*` to an `std::string` in term of a move-assignment, whose definition is:

> #### [`[string.cons]/32`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.cons-32)
>
> ```
> basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& str)  noexcept(/*...*/)
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Move assigns as a sequence container, except that iterators, pointers and references may be invalidated.

This shows that the Committee let the implementation choose freely between an invalidating operation and a more conservative one. And to make things even clearer:

> #### [`[basic.string]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.require-4)
>
> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_­string` sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_­string object:
>
> - (4.1) as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const `basic_­string` as an argument.
> - (4.2) Calling non-const member functions, except `operator[]`, `at`, `data`, `front`, `back`, `begin`, `rbegin`, `end`, and `rend`.

---

> I ask because i'm depending on this to avoid heap fragmentation.

`std::string` takes as template-parameter an allocator. If you're really concerned by a possible heap fragmentation, you could write your own, which with some heuristics could have an allocation strategy suited for your needs.

In practice, most implementations I know of would not reallocate memory in the case of your question. This can be checked by testing and/or checking your implementation doc and eventually source code.

Comment: You can imagine how undesirable such a guarantee would be (presuming it was given), if you had the Gettysburg Address stored in a string, and then replaced it with "Hello World."

Answer (score 13):

[CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) states that assignment to a pointer-to-char

> Replaces the contents with those of null-terminated character string pointed to by s as if by *this = basic_string(s), which involves a call to Traits::length(s).

This "as if" actually boils down to an rvalue assignment, so the following scenario is quite possible:

1. A fresh temporary string is created.
2. *This* string steals its contents as via assignment to an rvalue reference.

Comment: cppreference is usually reliable, but the quoted statement implies that there is a guaranteed buffer replacement, which is bollocks. Other than that it's a good conceptual model. But it's just *marginally* simpler than the standard's description, quoted in YSC's answer, which would therefore be preferable.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf cppreference is paraphrasing the standard [`[string.cons]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.cons-36)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Does it really? It says "as if", which, in Standard, always means "with regard to observable side effects, aside from few those of constructions/destructions".

Comment: @rustyx it's allowed to do either. You can conceptualise it as the temporary stealing the existing allocation, then returning it.

Comment: @rustyx The standard just talks about the effect. Given that the effect of `x = "hi";` is the same as the effect of `x.assign("hi");`, an implementation would do the efficient thing for both. libstdc++, for instance, has its `operator=(const CharT*)` just directly call `assign`

Answer (score 4):

> Is it guaranteed by the standard that std::string will not give back allocated memory spontaneously if reassigned from a string of a smaller size?

Regardless of the actual answer (which is "No, no guarantee") - you should employ the following principle: **If it's not obvious that it has to be the case, then don't assume it is the case.**

In your specific case - if you want tight control of heap behavior, you might not even want to use `std::string`s at all (maybe; it depends). And you might not want to use the default allocator (again, maybe); and you might want to [memoize strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805969/writing-universal-memoization-function-in-c11); etc. What you should absolutely do is make fewer assumptions, measure if possible, and have explicit design to ensure your needs are met.

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are short (up to 15 or 22 bytes, depending on the compiler/std lib) and you are using a relatively recent compiler in C++11 or later mode, then you are likely to benefit from the [Short String Optimization](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/std-string/) (SSO). In this case the string contents are not separately allocated on the heap.

This link also contains a lot of details on common implementations and allocation strategies.

However, both of the strings in your example are too long for SSO.

Comment: Is it guaranteed by the standard? Is SSO guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: @pipe No it isn't, what Paul implied in: _"you are **likely** to benefit from the Short String Optimization (SSO)"_.

Comment: @YSC Ok, but the question is rather specific, and OP already knows that it is likely to happen since he depends on it, so I don't understand what this actually answers.

Comment: @pipe I agree this answer is slightly off, but it was answered right after OP asked their question. The question wasn't tagged [tag:language-lawyer] at that time, and get edited after that. This is answering part of OP concern (mem frag) and provides an interesting insight. I've upvoted it for what it's worth.

Comment: It's not meant to be a full answer, just a complement for the case of SSO. I think that the link is quite interesting regarding practical measures of std::string performance.