# Ways to memoize in c++, Dynamic programming

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am fairly new to dynamic programming, i have seen people, memoize in javascript using objects. But i would like to know what will be the most efficient way to memoize in c++.
Which data structure should i use, is map good? orr is there something better, please let me know.

Comment: In JS more or less everything is a kind of object. As for what data structure to use, it depends on what you need to memoize, and how you need to access the memoized data. You could use a single `static int` variable if all you want is a single `int` value "memoized".

Comment: This is hard to answer without a more concrete problem. Probably a `std::unordered_map` is the most generic solution, but depending on the problem a `std::vector` might be more suitable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing Universal memoization function in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805969/writing-universal-memoization-function-in-c11)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use **unordered_map** instead of **map**.

The reason is that the **time complexity** for the **search operation** are as follow:

- unordered_map = O(1)
- map = O(log(N))

The reason is that **unordered_map** works as a hash table while **map** works as a binary tree.

Similarly, you can also use **unordered_set** instead of **set** for the same reason:

The **time complexity** for the **search operation** are as follow:

- unordered_set = O(1)
- set = O(log(N))

Comment: One should bear in mind that `unordered_map` has O(1) **amortized** time complexity, but `map` guarantees `O(log N)` on **each** search operation. This is a general note, for DP problems most likely is doesn't matter.