# cache last function return value

Tags: c++, caching, std

I want to implement caching of last function return value. I'm not sure if something like this already exists in the C++ Standard Library.

**Justification**

With C++ Standard algorithms, predicates, etc. it is often comes a situation when function is called many times consequently with the same argument and function execution could be quite long. For example, when you run `std::find_if` on the array of indexes while their values are still the same, but comparison could take significant time, like comparisons of underlying strings, getting values from maps, etc.

For example, in ranges this is planned to be solved with [cache_last](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2760r1.html#cache_last) adapter.

That’s why I am asking, is there something that could be used to achieve the same with other kinds of code? Or do I need to write my own?

**The code**

Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5nnWq79Tz):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Fn, typename I, typename O>
class CacheLast {
private:
    bool initialized=false;
    I last_arg = {};
    O last_res = {};
    std::function<Fn> fn;
public:
    CacheLast(Fn arg_fn) : fn(arg_fn) {}

    const O& operator()(const I& arg) {
        if (initialized && arg == last_arg) {
            return last_res;
        }
        initialized = true;
        last_arg = arg;
        return last_res = fn(arg);
    }

};

// Some funtion which could take time to calculate
size_t function(const std::string& s) {
    return s.length();
}

int main()
{
    auto ruler = CacheLast<decltype(function),std::string, size_t>(function);

    std::cout << ruler("First") << "\n";
    std::cout << ruler("Second") << "\n";
    std::cout << ruler("Second") << "\n";  // This is already taken from cache
}
```

Comment: "something that could be used to achieve " is way way to vague. PS What does that code have to do with your question? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805969/writing-universal-memoization-function-in-c11

Comment: This post is under discussion at [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428185/3404097).

Comment: Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: What I wrote was, "What does that code have to do with your question?". PS It's not clear what you are trying to ask, but it seems like maybe you want to cache & are asking for implementation idioms or library routines that could help such an idiom. Asking with no specifics is too vague & you give no specific example to be cached with whaterver specific goal you want that you don't explain in detail (though maybe your code is an example of something to do with what you're trying to ask but you don't explain). [ask] [Help] Please act per feedback on the meta question you posted.

Comment: @tgdavies, thank you so much. Despite the fact that they consider more complex task with keeping many values with map, I loved the idea that there is no need in the struct and function which returns lambda can be used instead as in the first answer in that topic; I will re-implement in this way. The thing is that I am surprised that no 'cache_last' functionality in `std` since it could be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern can be achieved with lambdas. Less generic, but potentially easier to implement on the fly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

size_t function(const std::string& s) {
  return s.length();
}

int main() {
  std::string lastQueried;
  size_t lastResult;
  bool initialized = false;
  auto ruler = [&lastResult, &lastQueried, &initialized] (const std::string& s) {
    if(initialized && s == lastQueried) {
      return lastResult;
    }

    initialized = true;

    lastQueried = s;
    lastResult = function(s);
    return lastResult;

  };

  std::cout << ruler("First") << "\n";
  std::cout << ruler("Second") << "\n";
  std::cout << ruler("Second") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Of course, it could. My question is different, is there is something ready exactly for this or something that could be easy applied (like one line solution) for this. To explain better, just show how your code would look like if you need to wrap up a second function there. My code would require to add one line. Yours?

Comment: The answer "no" isn't that interesting, though. There's no existing standard library facility to do this, and asking for other libraries is explicitly off-topic (although I don't know of any anyway).

Comment: @Useless, the answer "no" gives me green light to implement my own version; so it is very interesting for me. I just want to avoid reinventing the wheel, since robust implementation could be not so easy and straightforward.

Comment: as an aside, [this](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) is a great article on the (lack of) performance of `std::function`. if performance is a concern, maybe worth looking at?