# Avoid recomputation when data is not changed

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Imagine you have a pretty big array of double and a simple function `avg(double*,size_t)` that computes the average value (just a simple example: both the array and the function could be whatever data structure and algorithm). I would like that if the function is called a second time and the array is not changed in the meanwhile, the return value comes directly from the previous one, without going through the unchanged data.

To hold the previous value looks simple, I just need a static variable inside the function, right? But what about detecting the changes in the array? Do I need to write an interface to access the array which sets a flag to be read by the function? Can something smarter and more portable be done?

Comment: You're looking for [memoization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9729954/596781).

Comment: There are two basic techniques:  1) Have a counter that is incremented whenever your array is changed, and cache the current value of the counter with the cached function result.  2) Compute a checksum on the array when you compute the function result, and cache the checksum with the result.  Obviously (2) is slower, and it depends on the checksum being so robust that the odds of a false "match" is essentially zero.

Comment: @HotLicks If the algorithm is simple as getting the average, then computing a checksum may be even longer! I really want to avoid to run through all the data when not needed. 1) Is ok, is the same procedure that I was planning.. but I was looking for a better pattern.

Comment: @KerrekSB Tt's totally unclear to me how that would help.

Comment: Personally, I woudn't bother with changed/unchanged, I'd keep a "running sum" of the array, putting the array in a struct that adds new values and removes old values when they are replaced. This is the fastest as it makes mean a constant calculation rather than a O(n) calculation. Bonus points for putting in a mechanism to recalculate the whole sum every once and a while to prevent double errors from accumulating.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams that consists somehow in tying the algorithm to the data, it's nice but when the algorithm is more complex than averaging it may become pretty hard...

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, still, this is your best bet for speed for anything that can be calculated monotonically (mean, stddev, ect). Else, you'll have to go the @HotLicks 1.

Comment: What's nonportable in this scheme?

Comment: @n.m. I don't know, it's probably fine, but as programming is not my principal field of study and interest, when something doesn't look straightforward I like to hear opinions from experts (I learnt a lot of tricks in this way!)

Comment: What @MadScienceDreams suggests is good if the function is as simple as average.  Depending on what you're doing, a "running average" is another option.  (The "running average" is "weighted" and gives more weight to recent values.)

Answer (score 1):

As Kerrek SB so astutely put it, this is known as "memoization."  I'll cover my personal favorite method at the end (both with `double* array` and the much easier `DoubleArray`), so you can skip to there if you just want to see code.  However, there are **many** ways to solve this problem, and I wanted to cover them all, including those suggested by others. Skip to the horizontal rule if you just want  to see code.

The first part is some theory and alternate approaches.  There are fundamentally four parts to the problem:

- Prove the function is idempotent (calling a function once is the same as calling it any number of times)
- Cache results keyed to the inputs
- Search cached results given a new set of inputs
- Invalidating cached results which are no longer accurate/current

The first step is easy for you: average is idempotent.  It has no side effects.

Caching the results is a fun step.  You obviously are going to create some "key" for the inputs that you can compare against the cached "keys."  In Kerrek SB's [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729212/memoized-recursive-factorial-function/9729954#9729954) example, the key is a tuple of all of the arguments, compared against other keys with `==`.  In your system, the equivalent solution would be to have the key be the contents of the entire array.  This means each key comparison is O(n), which is expensive.  If the function was more expensive to calculate than the average function is, this price may be acceptable.  However in the case of averaging, this key is terribly expensive.

This leads one on the open-ended search for good keys.  Dieter Lücking's answer was to key the array pointer.  This is O(1), and wicked fast to boot.  However, it also makes the assumption that once you've calculated the average for an array, that array's values never change, and that memory address is never re-used for another array.  Solutions for this come later, in the invalidation portion of the task.

Another popular key is HotLick's (1) in the comments.  You use a unique identifier for the array (pointer or, better yet, a unique integer idx that will never be used again) as your key.  Each array then has a "dirty bit for `avg`" that they are expected to set to true whenever a value is changed.  Caches first look for the dirty bit.  If it is true, they ignore the cached value, calculate the new value, cache the new value, then clear the dirty bit indicating that the cached value is now valid. (this is really invalidation, but it fit well in this part of the answer)

This technique assumes that there are more calls to `avg` than updates to the data.  If the array is **constantly** dirty, then avg still has to keep recalculating, but we still pay the price of setting the dirty bit on every write (slowing it down).

This technique also assumes that there is only one function, `avg`, which needs cached results.  If you have many functions, it starts to get expensive to keep all of the dirty bits up to date.  The solution is an "epoch" counter.  Instead of a dirty bit, you have an integer, which starts at 0.  Every write increments it.  When you cache a result, you cache not only the identity of the array, but its epoch as well.  When you check to see if you have a cached value, you also check to see if the epoch changed.  If it did change, you can't prove your old results are current, and have to throw them out.

Storing the results is an interesting task.  It is very easy to write a storing algorithm which uses up gobs of memory by remembering hundreds of thousands of old results to `avg`.  Generally speaking, there needs to be a way to let the caching code know that an array has been destroyed, or a way to slowly remove old unused cache results.  In the former case, the deallocator of the double arrays needs to let the cache code know that that array is being deallocated.  In the latter case, it is common to limit a cache to 10 or 100 entries, and have evict old cache results.

The last piece is invalidation of caches.  I spoke earlier regarding the dirty bit.  The general pattern for this is that a value inside a cache must be marked invalid if the key it was stored in didn't change, but the values in the array did change.  This can obviously never happen if the key is a copy of the array, but it can occur when the key is an identifing integer or a pointer.

Generally speaking, invalidation is a way to add a requirement to your caller: if you want to use `avg` with caching, here's the extra work you are required to do to help the caching code.

---

Recently I implemented a system with such caching invalidation scheme.  It was very simple, and stemmed from one philosophy: the code which is calling `avg` is in a better position to determine if the array has changed than `avg` is itself.

- There were two versions of the equvalent of `avg`: `double avg(double* array, int n)` and `double avg(double* array, int n, CacheValidityObject& validity)`.
- Calling the 2 argument version of `avg` never cached, because it had no guarantees that array had not changed.
- Calling the 3 argument version of `avg` activated caching.  The caller guarentees that, if it passes the same CacheValidityObject to `avg` without marking it dirty, then the arrays **must** be the same.

Putting the onus on the caller makes average trivial.  CacheValidityObject is a very simple class to hold on to the results

```
class CacheValidityObject
{
    public:
        CacheValidityObject(); // creates a new dirty CacheValidityObject

        void invalidate(); // marks this object as dirty


        // this function is used only by the `avg` algorithm.  "friend" may
        // be used here, but this example makes it public
        boost::shared_ptr<void>& getData();
    private:
        boost::shared_ptr<void>  mData;
};

inline void CacheValidityObject::invalidate()
{
    mData.reset(); // blow away any cached data
}

double avg(double* array, int n); // defined as usual

double avg(double* array, int n, CacheValidityObject& validity)
{
    // this function assumes validity.mData is null or a shared_ptr to a double
    boost::shared_ptr<void>& data = validity.getData();
    if (data) {
        // The cached result, stored on the validity object, is still valid
        return *static_pointer_cast<double>(data);
    } else {
        // There was no cached result, or it was invalidated
        double result = avg(array, n);
        data = make_shared<double>(result); // cache the result
        return result;
    }
}

// usage
{
    double data[100];
    fillWithRandom(data, 100);

    CacheValidityObject dataCacheValidity;
    double a = avg(data, 100, dataCacheValidity); // caches the aveerage
    double b = avg(data, 100, dataCacheValidity); // cache hit... uses cached result

    data[0] = 0;
    dataCacheValidity.invalidate();
    double c = avg(data, 100, dataCacheValidity); // dirty.. caches new result
    double d = avg(data, 100, dataCacheValidity); // cache hit.. uses cached result

    // CacheValidityObject::~CacheValidityObject() will destroy the shared_ptr,
    // freeing the memory used to cache the result
}
```

Advantages

- Nearly the fastest caching possible (within a few opcodes)
- Trivial to implement
- Doesn't leak memory, saving cached values only when the caller thinks it may want to use them again

Disadvantages

- Requires the caller to handle caching, instead of doing it implicitly for them.

If you wrap the `double* array` in a class, you can minimize the disadvantage.  Assign each algorithm an index (can be done at run time)  Have the `DoubleArray` class maintain a map of cached values.  Each modification to `DoubleArray` invalidates the cached results.  This is the most easy to use version, but doesn't work with a naked array... you need a class to help you out

```
class DoubleArray
{
    public:
        // all of the getters and setters and constructors.
        // Special note: all setters MUST call invalidate()

        CacheValidityObject getCache(int inIdx)
        {
            return mCaches[inIdx];
        }

        void setCache(int inIdx, const CacheValidityObject& inObj)
        {
            mCaches[inIdx] = inObj;
        }

    private:
        void invalidate()
        {
            mCaches.clear();
        }

        std::map<int, CacheValidityObject> mCaches;
        double*                            mArray;
        int                                mSize;
};

inline int getNextAlgorithmIdx()
{
    static int nextIdx = 1;
    return nextIdx++;
}


static const int avgAlgorithmIdx = getNextAlgorithmIdx();
double avg(DoubleArray& inArray)
{
    CacheValidityObject valid = inArray.getCache(avgAlgorithmIdx);
    // use the 3 argument avg in the previous example
    double result = avg(inArray.getArray(), inArray.getSize(), valid);
    inArray.setCache(avgAlgorithmIdx, valid);
    return result;
}

// usage
DoubleArray  array(100);
fillRandom(array);
double a = avg(array); // calculates, and caches
double b = avg(array); // cache hit
array.set(0, 5); // invalidates caches
double c = avg(array); // calculates, and caches
double d = avg(array); // cache hit
```

Comment: Your second solution is fine, I hate the first: so easy to forget a call to `dataCacheValidity.invalidate();` (especially if you are editing some existing code) and generate some nasty bugs. As you pointed out all other suggestions apply only to specific cases with some assumptions and in general do not solve my problem.

Comment: I'm glad one of the solutions looks reasonable to you.  The fundamental problem is that you're trying to reduce a O(n) problem to an O(1) problem (checking all values in the dictionary against a cached value vs. checking only one value).  To do so you must change the problem subtlety.  Each of those solutions is "best" in different programs; I'm glad one is "best" for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <limits>
#include <map>

// Note: You have to manage cached results - release it with avg(p, 0)! 
double avg(double* p, std::size_t n) {
    typedef std::map<double*, double> map;
    static map results;
    map::iterator pos = results.find(p);
    if(n) {
        // Calculate or get a cached value
        if(pos == results.end()) {
            pos = results.insert(map::value_type(p, 0.5)).first; // calculate it
        }
        return pos->second;
    }
    // Erase a cached value
    results.erase(pos);
    return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

Comment: @CortAmmon this is exactly the point. The content is changing from time to time! Moreover I don't want to cache all the previous values as it's a very unlucky case that the same array will come back after some modification.