# It is allowed to switch template arguments in a template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729954/476681) forward declare template class Memo one way, and implemented it's partial specialization in another way.

So, the forward declaration is :

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename...> struct Memo;
```

and the partial specialization this :

```
template <typename R, typename... Args, template <typename...> class Container>
struct Memo<Container, R, std::tuple<Args...>>
```

The Container template argument is switched with the variadic template argument (hopefully someone understood what I just wrote). The R is just the first element in the pack.

The code compiles fine, so I guess there should be a simple explanation of why it is allowed to do.

So, why is it allowed to switch template arguments in a template specialization? Is it because a template specialization is an independent type?

Comment: If you're talking about `<typename R, typename... Args, template <typename...> class Container>` - the order here doesn't matter.

Comment: A partial specialization is itself a template. Its own template parameters are unrelated to those the the template that's being specialized. As you can see, the original template parameters do appear in matching order: `Memo<Container, R, std::tuple<Args...>>`. Namely, `Container` matches `Container`, and `R, std::tuple<Args...>` is a two-element pack that matches the pack.

Comment: @jrok That is what I did not understand.I thought the order matters when you specialize a template.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the template argumments in a partial template specialization doesn't matter at all. Thats because a partial template specialization is not really a template, its only an specialization of an existing template.
That means the set of template parameters of a partial template specialization are not the parameters of a template, **are only the declaration of the set of generic parameters which the specialization uses/needs**.

Consider an example:

```
// A typelist template:
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list {};

// A metafunction for concatenating typelists (Forward declaration):
template<typename LIST1 , typename LIST2>
struct concat;

//The partial specialization of that template for typelists:
template<typename... Ts , typename... Us>
struct concat<type_list<Ts...> , type_list<Us...>>
{
    using result = type_list<Ts...,Us...>;
};
```

In the partial specialization of the `concat` metafunction, what we are doing is to specialize the template for two **unspecified** typelists. So the template parameters of the typelits are unspecified, that is, are generic. And we need to *"declare"* that generic parameters before using it.
Consider the template parameters of a partial template specialization only as declarations of the generic paraeters which the specialization needs. Because there are not real template parameters, they don't have the restrictions of template parameters: Note that in the specialization I have used two variadic packs, which is not allowed in a template.

Comment: the specialized template class in the question is a template. What you wrote is not completely true. The point is that specialized template (template or not) is a type (almost) independent of the template class it specialize