# How to store and get previously calculated value

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am new to C++. I have making a code to calculate Value but I am unsure to about how to get the previously calculated value, which it has calculated in last call. In my understanding a way to do so is store values in array, but I am unsure about the exact structure/way to do so. Thanks in advance.

```
double CalculateValue(Node* node)
{ 
float gamma=0.3;
double Value = 0.0;

Value = ((1-gamma)* previousValue)+ gamma); // how to get this previous value
if (Value > previousValue)
```

Comment: `static` might help, but it seems better to encapsulate that in a class and use a member.

Comment: Code a Fibonacci series program, you will learn it! I promise!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise avoiding global/static variable, it's probably a better idea to create a small class that just stores the value and has a member function to do the computation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the difference between the value returned by two calls to the function, then something along the lines of this should do the trick:

    `{
        const auto val1 = CalculateValue();
        const auto val2 = CalculateValue();
        std::cout << "Difference is: " << std::abs(val1 - val2) << std::endl;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the memoize pattern (not memorize, if you're googling for it). This might come handy: [Memoized, recursive factorial function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729212/memoized-recursive-factorial-function/9729954#9729954)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a class to achieve your goal 
(I haven't tested it, so there might be a few bugs here and there)

```
class Solution {
public:
    void init_value(double val){ // initalize the value
        _previousValue = val;
    }
    double CalculateValue(Node* node){
        float gamma=0.3;
        double Value = 0.0;

        Value = ((1-gamma)* _previousValue)+ gamma); // _value would be your previous value
        if (Value > _previousValue){ 
            //whatever you want to do in here
        }

        _previousValue = Value; // set _previousValue to the new calculated Value
        return Value;
    }
private:
    double _previousValue; // call init_value(val) to initliaze _previousValue = val OR you can hard code _previousValue if it is always like 0 or something
```

}

```
int main() {
    Solution solution = new Solution();
    solution.init_value(0);
    Node *node; // I don't know what your Node struct looks like so...
    double value = CalculateValue(node);
    return 0;
}
```